# Is there a function to perform massive updates on r?

Tags: r

I'm doing some tests with shinyapp.
Does anyone know any way to update the labels of all the sliders with the value of a "text input" without having to use the function "updateSliderInput" for each of them?

Pd: I paste a sample but it really would be 100 sliders

A greeting and thanks in advance

```
ui <- fluidPage(

  fluidRow(

    textInput("caption", "Const1", "strong"),

    box(width = 3, title = "box1",
        solidHeader = TRUE, status = "danger",

        # Sd slider:
        sliderInput(inputId = "c11",
                    label = "Con1",
                    value = 5, min = 1, max = 5),
        sliderInput(inputId = "c12",
                    label = "Con2",
                    value = 3, min = 1, max = 5,step = 1),
        sliderInput(inputId = "c13",
                    label = "Con3",
                    value = 4, min = 1, max = 5),
        sliderInput(inputId = "c14",
                    label = "Con4",
                    value = 3, min = 1, max = 5),
        sliderInput(inputId = "c15",
                    label = "Con5",
                    value = 2, min = 1, max = 5)
    ),

    box(width = 3, title = "box2",
        solidHeader = TRUE, status = "danger",

        # Sd slider:
        sliderInput(inputId = "c21",
                    label = "Con1",
                    value = 2, min = 1, max = 5),
        sliderInput(inputId = "c22",
                    label = "Con2",
                    value = 3, min = 1, max = 5,step = 1),
        sliderInput(inputId = "c23",
                    label = "Con3",
                    value = 2, min = 1, max = 5),
        sliderInput(inputId = "c24",
                    label = "Con4",
                    value = 4, min = 1, max = 5),
        sliderInput(inputId = "c25",
                    label = "Con5",
                    value = 4, min = 1, max = 5)
    )
  )
)

# Define server logic required to draw 
server <- function(input, output, session) {

  observe({
    text <- input$caption

    updateSliderInput(session, "c11", label =text, value = 3 )

})

}

# Run the application 
shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Comment: I'm pretty sure you could do it in a loop: `for (id in list_of_ids) {updateSliderInput(session, id, ...)}`

Comment: Gracias por la sugerencia @divibisan , pero intente una pequeña prueba y el bucle no funciona ¿Estoy haciendo algo mal?::

ui <- fluidPage(  

    sliderInput(inputId = "11",
                label = "Con1",
                value = 5, min = 1, max = 5),
    sliderInput(inputId = "12",
                label = "Con2",
                value = 3, min = 1, max = 5)
)
server <- function(input, output, session) {

for (id in 11:12) {updateSliderInput(session, id, label ="hellouu" , value = 3)}  

}